# How to synchronize scrolling of two listboxes?

Tags: jsf

I have two list boxes with one to one mapping. They are also scrollable. I would like to synchronize the scrolling between those two listboxes. For example, if I scroll down the first list box, then the second list box should scroll down automatically the same amount of items in such way that the options on the both the list boxes should always appear in the same row. How can I achieve this in JSF?

Comment: What HTML does it generate? A pair of `<select>` elements?

Comment: can you please elobrate Mr Matt,

Comment: Also, please take the time to understand how to format your posts: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: the Generated HTML would be some thing like this <select> <option value="Cheese"> Cheese </option> ... </select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with JavaScript. I'd recommend using jQuery (or another cross-browser JS library) to save you the aggravation of writing vanilla JavaScript that works in all major browsers.

If the generated markup looks like this:

```
<select id="foo"><!-- snip options --></select>
<select id="bar"><!-- snip options --></select>
```

Then this jQuery will keep them synced:

```
var bar = $('#bar').get(0);

$('#foo').change(function() {
    bar.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/X6ja5/)

Comment: thanks For replay Mr Matt i am already this using javaScript if select option 1 in first list box then option 1 in the second listbox is getting selected but ,if the option 1 is at the top in the first list box then option 1 in the secind list box is at the top or at the middle or at the bottom ,

Comment: i want to show both the options in the both the list boxes in the same line , Any help would be appriciated

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand the problem. Could you clarify? Perhaps edit the markup into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example.

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9b4m.png)

```
<select id="foo" size="3">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
  <option>E</option>
</select>
<select id="bar" size="3">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

var bar = document.querySelector("#bar");
$('#foo').scroll(function() {
  bar.scrollTop = this.scrollTop
  bar.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft
  console.log(this.scrollTop+ ' ' + this.scrollLeft);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dse8m97p/)